# Flutter RadioListTile inside List.generate not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with RadioListTile and I can't find an solution, I have a List < dynamic > composed of several Map < String, dynamic > I have to make sure that these Maps can be selected through a radio button, but whatever I put on groupValue and value doesn't work, or all or none are selected. How can I make sure that only one map is selected? Below is the code:

```
[...] return List.generate(
  sedi.length,
  (index) => RadioListTile(
    value: index,
    groupValue: sedi[index],
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        sedi[index] = value;
      });
    },
    title: SedeTextColumn(
      sedi[index]['ADDRESS'].toString(),
      sedi[index]['CITY'].toString(),
      sedi[index]['PROVINCE'].toString(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way a radio button works is it is selected if the value property is equal to the groupValue property, for a group of radios, the value should be different and the groupvalue should be the same, let's look at what those values are:

```
[...]
value: index
[...]
```

index is a number in this range: [0, sedi.length)

```
groupValue: sedi[index]
```

the group value is the nth value on sedi, that means it will be different for every radio button.

Finally, when you click a radio, you set the group value to be the current value, which is the index, so you are turning your list of maps into a list of indexes like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5 ...]
```

In order to fix this, first you should declare an integer to signify the selected value outside of the build method:

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Then you can go like this:

```
value: index.
selectedValue: selectedIndex,
onChanged: (value) {
  setState(() => selectedIndex = index);
}
```

This will make all radio buttons have the same groupValue (`selectedIndex`) and a different value (`index`) You also implicitly change the groupValue when selecting a radio by changing the selectedIndex to be equal to the current index

Hopefully that will solve your problem.